# Inserting span via jquery leads to wrong layout

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a `paragraph` as part of a `radio input` with some text as `span`. I want to use `jquery` to add another `span` element in between. A kind of summary of the text. When I insert it by hand and render the HTML it looks nice. However when I run the script the new `span` element is rendered to close to the `radio input`. The resulting `DOM` looks the same however.

[image]

Can someone explain to me why the layout is different and what I need to do to make them look the same?

Here is the code snipped to reproduce it:

```js
(function( $ ) {
    'use strict';
    $(window).ready(function( ) {
        $('#second input').each(function() {
            const label = this.value.toUpperCase();
            $(`<span>${label}</span>`).insertAfter($(this));
      })
    });
})( jQuery );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <p>
        <input name="color" id="color_0" value="Green" type="radio">
        <span>GREEN</span>
        <span style="opacity:0.6">Item will be green.</span>
    </p>
</div>

<div id="second">
    <p>
        <input name="color" id="color_1" value="Green" type="radio">
        <span style="opacity:0.6">Item will be green.</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Difference is the whitespace in the first. Move the span in hard code first one to same line as input with no space and they are the same. Not saying this is the solution , just the demonstration of the issue

Comment: Add a space to the inserted `span`: `$("<span> ${label}</span>").insertAfter($(this));`

Comment: Note that using a `<label>` here would give user a bigger target for the radio click and better accessibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because inline elements render the line breaks between them as spaces. If you remove the line breaks between `<input>` and `<span>` you will see that the space is gone.

To add the space programatically you can simply add a space inside the `<span>` content.

```js
(function( $ ) {
    'use strict';
    $(window).ready(function( ) {
        $('#second input').each(function() {
            const label = this.value.toUpperCase();
            $(`<span> ${label}</span>`).insertAfter($(this));
      })
    });
})( jQuery );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <p>
        <input name="color" id="color_0" value="Green" type="radio"><span>GREEN</span>
        <span style="opacity:0.6">No space for me.</span>
    </p>
</div>

<div>
    <p>
        <input name="color" id="color_0" value="Green" type="radio">
        <span>GREEN</span>
        <span style="opacity:0.6">Item will be green.</span>
    </p>
</div>

<div id="second">
    <p>
        <input name="color" id="color_1" value="Green" type="radio">
        <span style="opacity:0.6">Item will be green.</span>
    </p>
</div>
```